# upgrade apache to apache2?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have an existing site that has been running for years.  I have been keeping the OS (Linux Debian) updated, but I never upgraded apache to apache2?  Is this worth the effort?

Comment: Hi JoelFan,
You can setup a test Debian VM or Box and test your website on it to see if you would get any problems, or you can create an exact as to what your site is running on and then do a apache upgrade to see if and what problems you may encounter - Just a suggestion.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apache 1.3 has been declared end-of-life and is not maintained anymore so even if it is still receiving security update, this will end sometime and I would recommend upgrading.
[apache doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/)

Answer (score 0):

If its working for you, and still receiving security fixes. No.